# why get AppLocalizations is null in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am follow [this doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) to implement international in my apps, this is my pubspec.yaml:

```
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: 0.17.0-nullsafety.2
```

but when I get the apps Localizations in project like this:

```
 CruiseLocalizations cruiseLocalizations = CruiseLocalizations.of(context);
  var home = cruiseLocalizations.cruiseNavigatorHome;
```

why the `cruiseLocalizations` return null? what should I do to fix this? this is my app entry code:

```
import 'package:Cruise/src/page/home/page.dart';
import 'package:Cruise/src/page/user/login/page.dart';
import 'package:fish_redux/fish_redux.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:Cruise/src/common/theme.dart';
import 'package:Cruise/src/common/view_manager.dart';
import 'package:fish_redux/src/redux_component/page.dart' as fishPage;
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

class CruiseApp extends HookWidget {
  const CruiseApp({@required this.theme, @required this.view});

  final ThemeData theme;
  final ViewType view;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currentTheme = ThemeManager.fromThemeName("lightTheme");

    final AbstractRoutes routes = PageRoutes(
      pages: <String, fishPage.Page<Object, dynamic>>{
        'entrance_page': LoginPage(),
        'home': HomePage()
      },
    );

    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Cruise',
        theme: currentTheme,
        localizationsDelegates: [
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: [
          const Locale('en', ''), // English, no country code
          const Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: 'zh'), // Chinese *See Advanced Locales below*
        ],
        //home: HomeNew(),
        home: routes.buildPage('home', null),
        onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
          return MaterialPageRoute<Object>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return routes.buildPage(settings.name, settings.arguments);
          });
        });
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you import Flutter `localizations` and add pass them to `MaterialApp` constructor in `lib/main.dart`?

Comment: I do not know how to pass localizations into MaterialApp, I have pasted my MaterialApp code. @JohnJoe

Comment: I think you don't need to initialize again. `CruiseLocalizations.of(context).cruiseNavigationHome` is good enough.

Comment: try print home, what you get?  `var home = CruiseLocalizations.of(context).cruiseNavigationHome;`

Comment: `CruiseLocalizations.of(context) ` is null ,so I could not get `CruiseLocalizations.of(context).cruiseNavigationHome` value @JohnJoe